# openssl_decryption fails to reveal plain-text

Tags: php, encryption-symmetric

I am using `openssl_encrypt` and `openssl_decrypt` to transfer a secure message. It works fine but sometimes fails to reveal the actual message. The whole message is fine except the last few bytes. I guess something is wrong with **OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING**. Can anyone explain why this happens? I'm using `ENC_CIPHER_ALGORITHM=AES-256-CFB`

```
public function encryptMessage($message)
{
    // get parameters 
    $algorithm = getenv('ENC_CIPHER_ALGORITHM'); 
    $private_key = hex2bin(getenv('ENC_PRIVATE_KEY')); 
    $init_vector = hex2bin(getenv('ENC_INIT_VECTOR'));
    
    $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    
    //SIGNATURE = MESSAGE;TIMESTAMP 
    $plaintext = $message.';'.$time;

    // generate cipher
    $cipher = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $algorithm, $private_key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $init_vector);

    return $cipher;
}

public function decryptMessage($chipher)
{
    // get parameters 
    $algorithm = getenv('ENC_CIPHER_ALGORITHM'); 
    $private_key = hex2bin(getenv('ENC_PRIVATE_KEY')); 
    $init_vector = hex2bin(getenv('ENC_INIT_VECTOR'));

    // decrypt
    $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($chipher, $algorithm, $private_key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $init_vector);

    return $plaintext;
}
```

Expected Output: (Normally looks like this)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "message"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-08-13 10:04:35"
}
```

Corrupted Output: (Sometimes)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "message"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2020-08-13 10:04:5�"
}
```

**Updates:** I was sending the cipher using the GET method without using any URL encoding. Now I used the PHP rawurlencode() method. That solved the problem.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error but I am of course using my own private key and iv. Could your iv be changing between encrypt and decrypt calls? i.e. is something changing the ENC_INIT_VECTOR environment variable?

Comment: No. Both sides have the same key and iv.

Comment: I was sending the cipher using the GET method without using any URL encode. Now I'm using PHP rawurlencode() and it's working fine. Thanks, @Mark for your effort.